# Is there a way to restore a js callback after a crash?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Essentially i want to run a function which has an option to add a callback. This callback should be executed after some time ( 1s to 30 min ). In the timeframe the application could crash or the computer could just die.

What would be the best practice to restore the callback? Originally i wanted to create a database entry which restores the callback(s) after a crash, but i think that would be not possible, is there another way around this ?

```
run function ( number a, function b){
  doSomething(a)
  b()
}
```

If this helps to visualise, some pseudocode. I wanna `run(1, () => { doOtherThing()}` and have it restored after a crash, but i dont know the calling code so i cant just store some variable and use a switch case or similar to restore all callbacks.

EDIT: Maybe i am completely on the wrong track and someone could hint me to a different way of solving this?

Comment: I think your only sane option is to try/catch things and not allow it to actually crash.

Comment: I mean the server itself could crash at some point right ? That would lead to a crash one way or the other.

Comment: callbacks usually take an error as their first param, so your function can accept both a successCallback and an errorCallback to rollback your change.

if you want to minimize the risk of the server/app crashing, just run it on a different process/thread/server/lambda function separated from your app and deploy it to some cloud provider.

Comment: So bassically if you can persist information and can guarantee it is consistent you can extrapolate - but a crash means you cant ... ? i had a similar situation with a mcu - i decoupled responsibility. the loop is on a stable system and pushes executions - logs failures also

Comment: That would be an option if the code throws an error in that function but there are running many other things in the background and the server istelf could also die which would lead to not executing anything afterwards ..

Comment: @Estradiaz okay so you think the only option for me is another system that is super simple, but can not possibly crash?

Comment: Every system can crash for any reason...so no matter where you put it there is always going to be a chance so you will need to understand and mitigate that in your error handling on both sides.

Comment: @NemesisFLX no never said "only" ;) i mean you can also run hundreds of instances so the probability of your downtime is small or even zero

Comment: I guess that is true thanks!